# What is the difference between FileMode.Create and FileMode.Truncate?

Tags: c#

I don't really understand it:

`FileMode.Create` creates a new file if it doesn't exists, or overwrites one if it does.

`FileMode.Truncate` doesn't create a new file, but deletes the entire content of an existing one, so basically it also overwrites the file.

So why is there even the possibility to do:

```
public void DoStuff()
{
    using (FileStream fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.Truncate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

When it's enough to do:

```
public void DoStuff()
{
    using (FileStream fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Because both are basically using an empty file to write stuff into it

Comment: The .NET wrapper exposes everything that the underlying winapi function (CreateFile) is capable of.  You can have a very productive programming career without ever using everything.  Accidents [do happen](https://github.com/System-IO-Abstractions/System.IO.Abstractions/issues/357).

Comment: "what is the difference"? well, you _wrote it in your question_: "`Truncate` doesn't create a new file". when do you use it: when you want to overwrite the content of a file, but don't want to _create_ it if it doesn't already exists.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For `FileMode.Truncate` file must exist. If it doesn't you'll get an exception. `FileMode.Create` would create new file in this case.

[image]

Comment: But why should you use it then? You could stick with File.Create

Comment: For the same reason that you would use Single(), instead of First(). If your logic assumes that file should exist, it's better to use FileMode.Truncate to get notified that it doesn't and  there is a problem somewhere

Answer (score 0):

The question sounds like both options might be needed at the same time:

- if an old file is there, truncate it;
- if it is not there, create a new one.

My solution to this:

```
public void DoStuff()
{
    var fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);
    var fileMode = fileInfo.Exists ? FileMode.Truncate : FileMode.CreateNew;
    using (FileStream fs = File.Open(path, fileMode, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: `FileMode.Create` achieves the same thing as `fileInfo.Exists ? FileMode.Truncate : FileMode.CreateNew` ([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filemode#fields))